# Angularjs $routeProvider jshint errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jshint

I have this angular code

```
    (function() {
        'use strict';

        var sampleApp = angular.module('MyApp', [
            'ngRoute',
            'MyApp.controllers.Main'
        ]);

        sampleApp .config(['$routeProvider',
            function($routeProvider){
                $routeProvider.

                    when('/',{
                        templateUrl: '../templates/home.html',
                        controller: 'homeController'
                    }).

                    when('/one',{
                        templateUrl: '../templates/one.html',
                        controller: 'oneController'
                    }).

                    when('/two',{
                        templateUrl: '../templates/two.html',
                        controller: 'twoController'
                    }).
        }]);

    })();
```

and when I use jshint I get these errors.

```
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 5, Expected an identifier and instead saw '}'.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 5, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 6, Missing semicolon.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 6, Expected an identifier and instead saw ']'.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 6, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 7, Missing semicolon.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 7, Expected an identifier and instead saw ')'.
    src/app/app.js: line 27, col 7, Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.
    src/app/app.js: line 29, col 2, Expected ']' to match '[' from line 9 and instead saw ')'.
    src/app/app.js: line 29, col 5, Expected ')' and instead saw ';'.
    src/app/app.js: line 29, col 6, Missing semicolon.
    src/app/app.js: line 1, col 13, Unmatched '{'.
    src/app/app.js: line 29, col 10, Unrecoverable syntax error. (100% scanned).
```

I cant see how to change the angular to pass jshint

Comment: at first glance it seems just fine, like it would run no problem...

Comment: nine numbers aren't provided so it's tough to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    when('/two',{
                    templateUrl: '../templates/two.html',
                    controller: 'twoController'
                }).
```

The last "." should be a ";" instead so it should look like

```
     when('/two',{
                    templateUrl: '../templates/two.html',
                    controller: 'twoController'
                });
```